# Generalization of elementary matrices to diffeomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

Any invertible matrix can be written as a product of elementary matrices (row-switching, row-multiplying and row-addition). Is there a similar concept for diffeomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$? I'm looking for "elementary diffeomorphisms" analogous to elementary matrices that can be composed to generate any diffeomorphism. My hypothesis is that the following "elementary diffeomorphisms" would be enough to generate any diffeomorphism:

**Permutation of components** (analogous to row-switching) of the form

$$a(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_2, x_1, x_3)$$

**Element-wise rescaling** (analogous to row-scaling) of the form

$$a(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1, b(x_2), x_3)$$

where $b$ is a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

**Pairwise mixing** (analogous to row-addition) of the form

$$a(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (c(x_1, x_2), x_2, x_3)$$

such that the map $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (c(x_1, x_2), x_2)$ is a diffeomorphism.

Any thoughts on how to prove/disprove this? Any references that could be helpful?

I'm just realizing now that the third type actually includes the second type, so I suspect only the first and third types are sufficient.

Comment: This sounds difficult, if not impossible, as diffeomorphisms are a lot more squishy than linear maps (still got nightmares about that beast called cotangens), in particular they are a lot bigger class than just linear maps. You even got a lot more objects you would need to think about, as there are a lot differential manifolds out there, and I have no idea why $\mathbb{R}^n$ with canonical structure should be any special. If you are talking holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ though, there I think something could work.

Comment: As Spivak uses in his proof of the change of variables theorem in *Calculus on Manifolds*, you can write a diffeomorphism as a composition of diffeomorphisms each of which is the identity in at least one coordinate.

Comment: @TedShifrin Combining that with an induction on dimension seems to be a proof